# inline usage of import with typescript 1.6 and es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript1.6

I am looking at updating some older js libs I have to typescript using the ES6 conventions, however I have come across a stumbling point.

So historically when I loaded a JSON file dynamically I would do something like this:

```
this.someFunctionWhichDoesStuff = function() {
   var config = require(theConfigDir); // theConfigDir was a variable
   // ... other stuffs
}
```

This worked fine, and I would also in some cases dynamically include some modules from a folder too:

```
this.someFunctionWhichDoesStuff = function() {
   var actualImplementationToUse = require(theDirectoryWithImplementation); // theConfigDir was a variable
   // ... other stuffs
}
```

This allowed me to switch implementations based upon configuration at earlier points, and worked well enough. Key points to note here are that the resolvers for the modules are variables not static text and that they are being run inside of functions not at root level.

So with this in mind I went over to the es6 style module inclusion in TS and realised I cannot do the above, as this is not valid syntax:

```
public someFunctionWhichDoesStuff() {
       import actualImplementationToUse from theDirectoryWithImplementation;
       // ... other stuffs
    }
```

And it makes sense, as I know ES6 modules need to statically resolve modules, so I am cool with that, however in the typescript 1.6 world I am unsure how to resolve this as `var includedModule = require(theDirectory);` seems to be invalid as it doesnt know about `require`, which may be solved with inclusion of the node js `d.ts` file, however I was hoping someone could give some steering as to what the desired approach is in the new es6 world going forward?

Comment: Add the typings for require, I'm using it to allow for webpack requires of views/styles... https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#loading-other-resources-and-code-splitting

Comment: sure I know I can do this, but is there a more `es6` way of doing this? i.e if I use require I am locked into using require on all consumers (be it browser or node), I imagine there isn't but I just wanted to check before I went down this route.

Answer (score 0):

> sure I know I can do this, but is there a more es6 way of doing this? i.e if I use require I am locked into using require on all consumers (be it browser or node), I imagine there isn't but I just wanted to check before I went down this route.

ES6 spec *doesn't specify a module loader anyways* (SystemJS is just a sample non-standard implementation) and mostly you want to transpile down to es5. So using `require` is not a bad idea (especially for non `.ts`/`.js` files)

Comment: Sure but the ES6 spec includes the notion of modules and import/export so SystemJS is just a placeholder until ES6 module syntax is supported natively right? Anyway that to one side I would be wanting to include ts files in the latter scenario. There are many ways to sidestep the problem, like just use require and treat it like an any object, or include all possible incarnations via import and just pick the right one I want (but that sounds messy). There may not be a nice way to solve the problem, as the dynamic require calls were handy and succinct in what they were doing.